# How to find out the stream length for CreateBlockBlobFromStream method

Tags: node.js, azure, stream

I'm trying to upload a streams with azure-storage, but the method `CreateBlockBlobFromStream` needs the stream length. I not sure where to geth the length.

My code

```
const Readable = require('stream').Readable;
const rs = Readable();

rs._read = () => {     
    //here I read a file, loop through the lines and then generate some xml
};

const blobSvc = azure.createBlobService(storageName, key);
blobSvc.createBlockBlobFromStream ('data','test.xml', rs, ???, (err, r, resp) => {});
```

Comment: Do you have any update?

Comment: Will try this out today or tomorow. I have been on holiday :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Instead of `createBlockBlobFromStream` try using [createWriteStreamToBlockBlob](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node/blob/master/lib/services/blob/blobservice.js#L3153).

The following code example pushes the letters a-z into *myblob.txt*.

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
const Readable = require('stream').Readable;
const rs = Readable();

var c = 97;
rs._read = () => {     
  rs.push(String.fromCharCode(c++));
  if (c > 'z'.charCodeAt(0)) rs.push(null);
};

var accountName = "youraccountname";
var accessKey = "youraccountkey";
var host = "https://yourhost.blob.core.windows.net";
var blobSvc = azure.createBlobService(accountName, accessKey, host);

rs.pipe(blobSvc.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob('mycontainer', 'myblob.txt'));
```

If you want to read a file with a readable stream, the code will look like this:

```
var fs = require("fs");
// ...
var stream = fs.createReadStream('test.xml');
stream.pipe(blobSvc.createWriteStreamToBlockBlob('mycontainer', 'test.xml'));
```

Comment: How come this function is not in the doc ?

Comment: The API Reference for this function can be seen at http://azure.github.io/azure-storage-node/BlobService.html#createWriteStreamToBlockBlob

Answer (score 0):

Please see another question related to this. ([get a stream's content-length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9240724/get-a-streams-content-length))

Or you can use any npms to get the length of the file stream. (Ex. https://github.com/joepie91/node-stream-length)